# On the stabler tautomer in amide-imidic acid tautomerism

Tags: stability, hydrolysis, tautomer, amides, nitriles

In the section on acid-catalysed hydrolysis of nitriles, [this](https://www.chemistrysteps.com/the-mechanism-of-nitrile-hydrolysis-to-carboxylic-acid/) webpage has the following line of reasoning;

> ...the more stable amide tautomer predominates the (following) equilibrium.

[image]

([credit](https://www.chemistrysteps.com/the-mechanism-of-nitrile-hydrolysis-to-carboxylic-acid/))

How are the relative stabilities of these tautomers compared? I made up a reason of the resonance structure for the amide one having negative and positive charges on oxygen and nitrogen respectively, and vice versa for the imidic acid one, but I'd like clarification on that.

There's also another hand-wavy thing I thought about of the double bond being stable on the more electronegative atom, oxygen. Is that correct, too?

Comment: For future reference: If there is an illustration you refer to, take a moment to include it _here_ on ChemSE altogether with a note of credit.  The reason:  Perhaps the address of the webpage you refer to changes (or is closed for whatever reason).  This would yield your question less easy to access, than necessary.  Regardless if «amdie» looks like a typo, or not.

Answer (score 7):

The *relative* stability of the two tautomers (two isomers differing how protons are bound) may be assessed from the equilibrium constant you may formulate for the two.  Deriving from above illustration, it would be

[image]

to indicate that this is dynamic, with a back and forward reaction at microscopic level.  Once formulated *as such*, you probably recall $\Delta{}_RG = -RT \ln{}K$ to relate between the sample temperature $T$, the universal gas constant $R$, the free reaction enthalpy $\Delta{}_RG$ and the equilibrium constant $K$.

Depending on the substrate, you may use spectroscopic evidence (e.g., $\ce{^1H}$-NMR spectroscopy) to assess the concentration of the two forms.  Equally, based on prior work by others, there are databases to either list these values, or provide a prediction (i.e., *an educated guess*) about $K$.  Knowing these equilibria is important to anticipate the likelihood of chemical reactions. It equally offers insight regarding the pharmaceuticals and their uptake, anabolism, interaction with the body (metabolism), and catabolism and eventual elimination, too.

One of the databases available to the public is *Tautobase* ([2020JChemInfModel1085](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jcim.0c00035)). It is implemented in the freely available [*DataWarrior*](https://openmolecules.org/datawarrior/index.html) program allowing you a search-by-(sub)structure.  With some luck, one of the 1680 pairs matches your substrate closely enough, too.  In the simplest case one may imagine, however, the amide is strongly favoured:

[image]

The database backs *this particular* entry with the publications [1998JAmChemSoc10359](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja980354e) and [2001JAmChemSoc2681](https://doi.org/10.1021/ja0036763).

Comment: +1, Thanks for the amazingly well-researched answer. But I was asking about the *reasons* you make up to explain the observation that we already know, not the *values* that tell you which the preferred tautomer is themselves. Could you clarify whether my guesses at these reasons are valid?

Comment: I understood your question «How are the relative stabilities of these tautomers compared?» as a search on how experimental evidence is collected.

Comment: @HarryHolmes Neglecting influence by solvent / reaction conditions, for the isolated molecule the total energy including a carbonyl $\ce{C=O}$ may be a different one compared to $\ce{C=C}$ (as in keto-enol equilibria), or $\ce{C=N}$ (as for the case of imidic acid). It would be nice if there is a second perspective including this aspect (and maybe tabulated data like [these](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Chemical_Bonding/Fundamentals_of_Chemical_Bonding/Bond_Energies)), too.

Comment: Okay, is there any resource from where the molecule energies are accessible? And is there any weight to the resonance thing I was going on about?

Comment: Last picture shows different type or tautomerism.

Comment: @Mithoron: yes, but I don't see how that explains it. Moreover, it looks like the product-side of the equlibrium has something different from the imidic acid in the question.

Comment: @Buttonwood: the double bond in the original equations was to the nitrogen in the imidic acid, but the last pic has it into the organic fragment.

Comment: @HarryHolmes True, the screen photo is about the putative equilibrium about formamide and amino-ethenol.  For the current version of DataWarrior (April 2021) and tautobase (2020), this is the most similar pair with a formide-like pattern. The pair with an imidic acid equally has an amino-ethenol on the other side of the equation.  For the energies, I hoped one of the quantum-chem savy readers either a) could point to a compilation, or b) offer an insight / result of computation.